# Spring oauth2 oauth/token http 405 error POST method not supported

Tags: spring, security, spring-security-oauth2

I am facing HTTP 405 error for oauth/token on tomcat 8(linux), while other POST requests are working fine.

Above issue not appears on windows localhost tomcat 8.

Any clues ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, it turned out to be caused by a controller method which I used to map all endpoints to something else i.e:

```
@GetMapping("**")
```

Resolved the issue with changing the all-matching endpoint to:

```
@GetMapping("/dev/**")
```

Answer (score 0):

My Problem got solved after adding the dependency below:

```
  @Bean
    public FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping endpointHandlerMapping() {
        return new FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The TokenEndpoint bean has a list of allowed HttpMethods. The default is now just HttpMethod.POST. Somehow calling the setAllowedRequestMethods after the TokenEndpoint bean has been created will fix this. I did this to fix it in a project:

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ProviderTokenGetAllowedBackwardsCompatible implements InitializingBean
{
    @Autowired
    private TokenEndpoint tokenEndpoint;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        tokenEndpoint.setAllowedRequestMethods(new HashSet<HttpMethod>() {{
            add(HttpMethod.GET);
            add(HttpMethod.POST);
        }});
    }
}
```